# Putting multiple element from ArrayList to a single Array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

Need some help to understand how I can put all the elements from an ArrayList to a single Array. Not sure if its possible to do it in a single Array.

Declaration

```
List componentNameList = new ArrayList(); 
String[] componentNameItem = soapApiCall.getComponentNames(); 
componentNameList.add(Arrays.toString(componentNameItem));
```

Here is the element of the ArrayList:

```
[[Index, Pattern, Smart, Intell][Index, Tree, Pet, Intel][Index, Pattern, Bear, Intell, Dog][Sky, Intern, Blond]]
```

Expected output for the Array

```
<Index><Pattern><Smart><Intell><Index><Tree><Pet><Intel><Index><Pattern><Bear><Intell><Dog><Sky><Intern><Blond>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to merge all the nested lists elements into an array with a single element with the provided format? if you want to flatten a nested list into a single array containing all those elements?

Comment: Smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it since your solution structure may not be the best.

Comment: Yes. That's what I want. Merge all nested list element into a single array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd suggest you not use raw types, nor do I suggest to add the string representation of an array to a raw type list.

Thus, change this:

```
List componentNameList = new ArrayList();
```

to this:

```
List<List<String>> componentNameList = new ArrayList<>();
```

then change this:

```
componentNameList.add(Arrays.toString(componentNameItem));
```

to this:

```
 componentNameList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(componentNameItem)));
```

Then you can accomplish the task at hand with streams like below:

```
String[] resultSet = componentNameList.stream() 
                                      .flatMap(List::stream) // flatten
                                      .toArray(String[]::new); // collect to array
```

then print:

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultSet));
```

Comment: I got an error stating "Incompatible types: invalid method reference, method stream in interface Collection<E> cannot be applied to given types. required: no arguement 
found:object

Comment: List componentNameList = new ArrayList();
String[] componentNameItem = soapApiCall.getComponentNames();
componentNameList.add(Arrays.toString(componentNameItem));

Comment: @MilesKim: show this as an [edit] to your original question since code does not display well in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. When I try to print the array it return an error. java.lang.ArrayStoreException. Not really sure what's going on.

Comment: @MilesKim don't know why you're getting that, consider looking at the edit.

Comment: @Aominè Is it something to do with the toArrayList? I tried Array.toString and get this error.
 java.lang.ArrayStoreException
 at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
 at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:408)

Comment: @MilesKim no. but I can guarantee that the code within my post is working 100% . However, `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` occurs when you try to store an object of a particular type in an array of objects of different types. so make sure you're not breaking this rule elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @Aominè Found the cause of it. Some other codes mess it up. Thank you so much for the guidance. Appreciate your help =)